# How to fix RSS feeds in OSQA?

Tags: windows, rss, osqa

When trying to access the RSS link in my Windows installation of OSQA, the error log shows the following error:

```
C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py TIME: 2013-05-09 17:46:37,956 MSG: base.py:handle_uncaught_exception:209 Internal Server Error: /feeds/rss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\osqa\[mysite.com]\forum\views\readers.py", line 73, in feed
    settings.APP_DESCRIPTION)(request)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\syndication\views.py", line 37, in __call__
    feedgen = self.get_feed(obj, request)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\syndication\views.py", line 97, in get_feed
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py", line 92, in get_current_site
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sites\models.py", line 25, in get_current
    current_site = self.get(pk=sid)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 132, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 349, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\osqa\[mysite.com]\forum\views\meta.py TIME: 2013-05-09 17:46:37,960 MSG: meta.py:error_handler:200 
        error executing request:
        PATH: /feeds/rss
        USER: fadder111 (60)
        METHOD: GET
        POST PARAMETERS:
        None
        GET PARAMETERS:
        None
        HTTP HEADERS:
                AUTH_TYPE: 
        wsgi.multiprocess: False
        HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER: 
        HTTP_COOKIE: greeting_set=True; csrftoken=482ec461eee5e692b60276b05ae2c41f; sessionid=49ed4088169860ce5f7abb10c573a999; __utma=87189386.1808482846.1368120178.1368120178.1368120178.1; __utmb=87189386.13.10.1368120179; __utmc=87189386; __utmz=87189386.1368120179.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
        wsgi.multithread: False
        SERVER_SOFTWARE: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
        SCRIPT_NAME: 
        LOCAL_ADDR: 10.0.2.144
        QUERY_STRING: 
        REQUEST_METHOD: GET
        REMOTE_USER: 
        PATH_INFO: /feeds/rss
        SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
        CERT_COOKIE: 
        AUTH_PASSWORD: 
        CONTENT_LENGTH: 0
        HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
        APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\osqa\[mysite.com]\
        HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
        HTTP_REFERER: http://[mysite.com]/
        SERVER_NAME: [mysite.com]
        REMOTE_ADDR: 69.157.47.xxx
        APPL_MD_PATH: /LM/W3SVC/38/ROOT
        INSTANCE_ID: 38
        HTTPS_KEYSIZE: 
        SERVER_PORT: 80
        REQUEST_URI: /feeds/rss
        CERT_SERIALNUMBER: 
        HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT: 
        URL: /feeds/rss
        HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE: 
        SCRIPT_FILENAME: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\osqa\[mysite.com]\feeds\rss
        wsgi.input: <__main__.InputStream object at 0x02BCA1D0>
        HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
        HTTP_HOST: [mysite.com]
        HTTPS: off
        SERVER_PORT_SECURE: 0
        CERT_SUBJECT: 
        CERT_ISSUER: 
        CERT_FLAGS: 
        PATH_TRANSLATED: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\osqa\[mysite.com]\feeds\rss
        wsgi.version: (1, 0)
        GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
        wsgi.run_once: False
        CSRF_COOKIE: 482ec461eee5e692b60276b05ae2c41f
        wsgi.errors: <__main__.TeeOutputStream object at 0x0298E9D0>
        REMOTE_PORT: 54728
        HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.8
        APPL_PATH: 
        LOGON_USER: 
        INSTANCE_NAME: [mysite.com]
        CONTENT_TYPE: 
        INSTANCE_META_PATH: /LM/W3SVC/38
        AUTH_USER: 
        DOCUMENT_ROOT: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\osqa\[mysite.com]\
        REMOTE_HOST: 69.157.47.121
        HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch

    wsgi.url_scheme: http
```

In Windows, I created the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings but this returns an error indicating it could not import the settings - Is it on sys.apth?

My OSQA installation is in C:inetpub\wwwroot\osqa\osqa.community.site (the dir name has periods in it).

How can I get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current OSQA version created for using with old version Django (1.3)
You need to make fixes for work with current version (1.5.4 right now).
Or check it out some forks on github, like this mine.
https://github.com/8c1/OSQA

Comment: What are some of the major issues that your version corrects?

Comment: Take a look at all changes in current Django 1.5 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#id2